# On-premise AD to Azure AD authentication/authorization for ASP.NET Core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, active-directory, authorization, azure-active-directory

I currently have an ASP.Net Core and Ionic(Angular) 1.x intranet application for my organization that authenticates the user using Active Directory (NTLM/Kerberos), and signs them in using `Identity` after a redirect from authorization failure.

Now with ASP.Net Core 2, I want to transition from on premise Active Directory, to Azure Active Directory so I can open the doors for some more interesting things, such as staff being able to log in externally using Azure AD Application Proxy. I still want to be able to persist some information about the users though, kind of like Identity let me do.

Right now in my experimentations, I am using ADAL.js (Active Directory Authentication Library) to authenticate my user, as I have disabled Windows Authentication.

This works great and I receive a token indicating who this person is, and I can access `[Authorize]` restricted API endpoints. How though, do I turn this token into a session on my Web API that I can sign a user in and persist information about them?

EDIT: Could one thing I do be to generate my token, but instead of using `AzureAdBearer` for authentication, I use cookie authentication and then on the server validate the token, and if valid manually set the user to be authenticated through `HttpContext.SignInAsync?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't turn the token into session because the web API is RESTful.

And you can get the identity info using the `User` property in the controller to acquire the authenticate user info from Asp.net core 2.0 web app.